# How to set angular build path for domain migrated?

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, dns

I am going to deploy angular project to amazon s3.
I have domain for this project.
Let's call it `mydomain.co`.

I installed ssl for cloudfront of this s3 bucket.

Let's call cloudfront url is `https://examplecloudfront.net`

I set CNAME www of `mydomain.co` to `https://examplecloudfront.net`.

Here, what base url I have to build my angular with?

I used `ng build --prod --base-href https://examplecloudfront.net/`

but it works only for couldfront url, not working for `https://www.mydomain.co`

it shows error like this.
`main.xxx.bundle.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'https://examplecloudfront.net/#/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'https://www.mydomain.co' and URL 'https://www.mydomain.co'.
Error: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'https://examplecloudfront.net/#/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'https://www.pitchexdata.com.au' and URL 'https://www.mydomain.co'.`

How to fix this error?
Thanks

Comment: Have you also set the `A record` to point to CloudFront?

Comment: No, but it works, I tested with simple html file.
It doesn't work only bucket replaced with angular dist files